# Implicit and Explicit waits are resulting in NoElementFound error but using Thread.sleep(someDuration) results in scripts running seamlessly

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am trying to automate android app where the user flow looks like this 
 
Click On Login > Enter UserName > Enter Password > Click on Next > Landing Page

On Landing Page there is an overlay screen followed by 4 navigation buttons at the bottom.

In script I am trying to click on one of the buttons.
We already have implicit wait of 5seconds and explicit wait of 30 seconds.

When I try to click on button before which we have called below method:

```
public void waitForPageToLoad(MobileElement id){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT_LONG);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(id));
}
```

The click operation results in NoElementFound error.
Whereas if we put Thread.sleep() it works fine.

Is there any thing that I am missing ? Any help would be really helpful.

Have tried different wait conditions like waitForElementToAppear, waitForElementToBeVisible

Comment: What is `id`? Can you add more of your code?

Comment: Updated the code snippet. Id is MobileElement passed from the method from where this function is called.(basically page object )